# Date picker leaks while using ARC in XCode 4.5

Tags: objective-c

```
  self.date = d;
  [self.datePicker setDate:date];
  self.dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
  [dateFormatter setTimeStyle: 0];
  [dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
  self.dateText.text = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
```

UIDevice RGB Color and CGColor are the leaks

Comment: I don't see any reference to color objects in your code...

Comment: This is not really a question, but I can also confirm this. Both UIDevice RGB and CGColor. Producing a memory warning doesn't purge them.